# Existence of a smooth function with a given kernel

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed set, then is there existing a smooth function $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$, such that
$$
(1)\quad f\ge 0,
$$
$$
(2) \quad f^{-1}(0)=K.
$$

Comment: Yes: first deal with the case where $K$ is the complement of an open ball, then jump to the general case writing $K$ as a countable union of such sets.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Did you mean countable *intersection*?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes (now I can't edit the commnet anymore).